# Scrolling buttons - with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working on a list that you can scroll through by clicking on buttons. And it also needs to have a scrollbar visible and working too. But I don't know how to edit my code to get them both to function. I can either have the buttons working or the scrollbar, not both. Can someone help?

```js
var itemsToShow = 3;

$('#scroll>li').each(function(i,k) {
    var ele = $(this);
    $(ele).attr('id', 'scroll' + i);

});


$('#up').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('#scroll0:hidden').length > 0)
    {
        // This means we can go up
        var boundaryTop = $('ul li:visible:first').attr('id');
        var boundaryBottom = $('ul li:visible:last').attr('id');

        if ($('ul li#'+ boundaryTop).prev().length > 0)
        {
            $('ul li#'+ boundaryTop).prev().show();
            $('ul li#'+ boundaryBottom).hide();
        }
    }
});

$('#down').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('#scroll li:last:hidden').length > 0)
    {
        // This means we can go down
        var boundaryTop = $('#scroll li:visible:first').attr('id');
        var boundaryBottom = $('#scroll li:visible:last').attr('id');

        if ($('#scroll li#'+ boundaryBottom).next().length > 0)
        {
            $('#scroll li#'+ boundaryBottom).next().show();
            $('#scroll li#'+ boundaryTop).hide();
        }
}
});
```

```css
.lg {
    overflow-x:auto; 
    height:90px;
    overflow-y:auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="lg">
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>

<div id="updown">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" id="up" href="#">up</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="down" href="#">down</a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Someone please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Retros, do you want to it click through the divs? Or scroll to the next group?

Comment: Hey ether, I want to scroll to the next li.

Comment: $('#scroll0:hidden').length is always give you 0. where is element with #scroll0 Id

Comment: So, you need to set a div to an id of `scroll` because in your example, your lis don't gain an id. Also, you aren't setting a `:hidden` state anywhere

Comment: Thank you ether!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you scroll to top and bottom:

https://jsfiddle.net/45cmhys8/

```
// Scroll to the top
$('a#up').on('click', function(){
   $('.lg').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
})
// Scroll to the bottom
$('a#down').on('click', function(){
   $(".lg").animate({ scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 600);
})
```

Comment: Simple, but effective! Thanks Keith!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scrollTop() function in jQuery to do this in a one-liner.

10 is the amount of pixels you want to jump up/down.

```
$('#up').click(function(){
  $('ul.lg').scrollTop($('ul.lg').scrollTop()- 10);
});

$('#down').click(function(){
  $('ul.lg').scrollTop($('ul.lg').scrollTop() + 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to literally show/hide the fields, which removes them from the flow of the browser. Rather then show/hide, you should probably set the scrollTop position of the scrollable div using javascript, rather then manipulate the elements inside of it.