# Issues in regards to a button with scrollTo() function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, scrollto

I am trying to write a button  with scrollTo(); but it doesn't seem to be working. Also, is there any way to get this function to work so it scrolls to an element (in my case a nav bar...) rather than pixel coordinates?

Here is my code:

```
<figure id="LoadVideo">
     <button type="button" onclick="ScrollDown()"> Scroll Down</button>
           <script>
                 function scrollDown(){
                      window.scrollTo(0,500);
                 }
           </script>
     <video id="LoadVid" autoplay src="images/LoadVid.mov" type="video/mov">
     </video>
   </figure>
```

Also if there could be any way to get animation on the button (like to come in after 7 seconds) that anybody can help with that would be awesome!

Thanks so much!

M.C.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237268/scrolling-buttons-with-jquery/43237593#43237593

Comment: I recall seeing this typo before...I guess it's more common than I thought. You wrote `onlick`...which is not an event that a computer can capture. You probably meant `onclick`. Also, since JavaScript is case-sensitive, make sure you call `scrollDown()` and not `ScrollDown()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no `lick` event :) (*you must mean `click`*) so `onclick` and function names are case sensitive so call `scrollDown` and not `ScrollDown`

```css
figure{height:2000px;}
```

```html
<figure id="LoadVideo">
     <button type="button" onclick="scrollDown()"> Scroll Down</button>
           <script>
                 function scrollDown(){
                      window.scrollTo(0,500);
                 }
           </script>
     <video id="LoadVid" autoplay src="images/LoadVid.mov" type="video/mov">
     </video>
   </figure>
```

For the other question, you can get the element you want to scroll to, gets its Y offset and scroll to that, or you can use the [`element.scollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

Comment: Thank you! I'd be lost without the fine people of stack!